# Your browser didn't send a complete request in time

Tags: support, google-chrome

I'm using latest stable version of Google Chrome.

Sometimes when I review questions on https://stackoverflow.com/, I see the following:

```
408 Request Time-out

Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
```

For example, today I received this error 6 times.

What is the problem?

Comment: See [408 Request Timeout, is it just me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80432) and [408 Request Time-outs still continues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208790)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377581), discovered and reported by Stack Overflow valued associate [Shane Madden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/167585/shane-madden), see [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/408-request-timeout-is-it-just-me/80501#comment764563_80501):

> I've reproduced this and confirmed that at least the 408s that I'm getting are exactly what are being discussed in the HAProxy blog post. [Bug has been filed for Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377581) and we'll be testing the suggested workaround within the next couple days. Is anyone seeing these 408s consistently on a good internet connection, and not using Chrome?

Chrome isn't handling 408 status responses from the HAProxy load balancer correctly.

The Stack Exchange team has applied a work-around to the HAProxy setup; the [problem *should* be resolved now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232275/140890).

Comment: Chrome is starting to become a parody of itself.